# Text-Indent in Safari, hides background image

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a strange bug in **safari** thats causing one of my button's to be clickable and in the right place, but be invisible due to `text-indent:-9999px;`

It has a background image which seems to disappear with the text-indent;

See here: http://jasper.limebuild.net/smitfield.html

Add product to cart and proceed to cart here: http://jasper.limebuild.net/checkout/cart

The checkout button is on the right underneath 'Grand Total'

Works fine in all other browsers but safari.

Thanks

Comment: Solved: Someone had added in the line -webkit-border-fix:line; into the css stylesheet for some strange reason which caused this image to break.

Answer (score 0):

give the image an id

then...
the css:

```
#image {
z-index: 9999;
}
```

tell me after if that works

Comment: I know no reason why someone would put an ID on an image like that. Just use a class instead, please.

Comment: I know no reason why someone would put a class on a image like that.
Its the same thing man, dont act like to show that you are a pro

Comment: 1. You could reuse this class to style other images/elements 2. You can easily override the styles of the image with other classes. 3. There's simply no good reason to use ID's **in CSS** at all.

Comment: Man its the same thing...no reason to use id on css?
What kind of sites do you make?

Comment: The image is a background image, it works fine in many other areas of the site

Comment: man do what i told to do. it may fix the problem, let me explain, all borwers have is own whay to read the css.

Comment: Theres no image to give an ID too.. its a background image.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "theres no image to give an id". are you telling me that image has ben fallen from the sky?

Comment: Sorry I misread. However adding a z-index doesn't fix the problem